# Uncaught TypeError: FormData constructor: Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLFormElement jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload PDF files using drag and drop. I am using jquery ajax.

```js
ajaxData = new FormData(form);
```

I tried `const form = $("form");`, `const form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]` but still getting the same error.

When I tried `const form = $("form")[0]`, and `const form = document.querySelector("form");` I got no error but got empty `<FileStorage: '' ('application/octet-stream')>` in my python script.

I have tried many solutions from SO but all of them mention above solutions.
Also, If I keep `ajaxData = new FormData()` I get no error but I get my file `<FileStorage: 'certificate.pdf' ('application/pdf')>` + another `<FileStorage: '' ('application/octet-stream')>`

Part of the code:

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

const container = document.querySelector(".container"),
  dropArea = container.querySelector(".drop_area"),
  form = container.querySelector("form"),
  button = container.querySelector(".pdf_btn_container"),
  btn = button.querySelector(".pdf_btn"),
  label = container.querySelector("label"),
  input = container.querySelector("input"),
  dropInfo = dropArea.querySelector(".drop_info"),
  body = document.querySelector("body"),
  icon = dropArea.querySelector(".icon"),
  loading = dropArea.querySelector(".loading"),
  orSpan = dropArea.querySelector(".or_span");

let file;
let ajaxData;

container.onclick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  input.click();
}
btn.onclick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
}

dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  dropArea.classList.add("drop_area--drag");
  container.classList.add("container--drag");
  orSpan.classList.add("or_span--drag");
  dropInfo.classList.add("drop_info--drag");
  btn.classList.add("pdf_btn--drag")
  icon.classList.add("icon--drag");
  button.classList.add("pdf_btn_container--drag");
});

["dragleave", "dragend"].forEach(action => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(action, (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    dropArea.classList.remove("drop_area--drag");
    container.classList.remove("container--drag");
    orSpan.classList.remove("or_span--drag");
    dropInfo.classList.remove("drop_info--drag");
    btn.classList.remove("pdf_btn--drag")
    icon.classList.remove("icon--drag");
    button.classList.remove("pdf_btn_container--drag");
  });
});

dropArea.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  dropArea.classList.add("drop_area--drag");
  container.classList.add("container--drag");
  orSpan.classList.add("or_span--drag");
  dropInfo.classList.add("drop_info--drag");
  btn.classList.add("pdf_btn--drag");
  icon.classList.add("icon--drop");
  loading.classList.remove("loading");
  loading.classList.add("loading--drop");
  button.classList.add("pdf_btn_container--drag");

  file = e.dataTransfer.files;
  console.log(file);
  if (file.length > 1 || file.length === 0) {
    alert("Multiple files selected!");
    dropArea.classList.remove("drop_area--drag");
    container.classList.remove("container--drag");
    orSpan.classList.remove("or_span--drag");
    dropInfo.classList.remove("drop_info--drag");
    btn.classList.remove("pdf_btn--drag")
    loading.classList.add("loading");
    loading.classList.remove("loading--drop");
    button.classList.remove("pdf_btn_container--drag");
    icon.classList.remove("icon--drag");
    icon.classList.remove("icon--drop");
  } else {
    file = file[0];

    $(function() {
      const $form = $("form");
      ajaxData = new FormData($form[0]);
      console.log(1, file);
      ajaxData.append($('input').attr('name'), file);
      console.log(2, file);
      console.log(ajaxData);
      $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: ajaxData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
          form.onsubmit = (ev) => {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            //ev.preventDefault();
          }
          $form.trigger('submit');

          console.log("Success");
        },
      });
    });
  }
});

document.getElementById("certificate").onchange = function() {
  console.log("Le bhai main bhi chal gya!");
  dropArea.classList.add("drop_area--drag");
  container.classList.add("container--drag");
  orSpan.classList.add("or_span--drag");
  dropInfo.classList.add("drop_info--drag");
  btn.classList.add("pdf_btn--drag");
  icon.classList.add("icon--drop");
  loading.classList.remove("loading");
  loading.classList.add("loading--drop");
  button.classList.add("pdf_btn_container--drag");
  console.log(document.getElementById("certificate").value);
  document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}
```

```css
body {}

.container {
  background-color: #227fbb;
  / / width: 1131 px;
  / / height: 396 px;
  //background-color: #227fbb;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container:hover {
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(44, 151, 222, 0.6), rgba(44, 151, 222, 0.2));
}

.container--drag {
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 189, 156, 0.4), rgba(0, 189, 156, 0.2));
}

.pdf_btn {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20standalone%3D%22no%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Csvg%20height%3D%22700%22%20id%3D%22svg8%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20185.20832%20185.20832%22%20width%3D%22700%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Asvg%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cdefs%20id%3D%22defs2%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20id%3D%22path2227%22%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23000000%3Bstroke-width%3A5.33076%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Around%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22m%20114.84828%2C39.943197%20v%2036.164064%20h%2026.24619%20z%20m%2026.24619%2C36.164064%201e-5%2C81.546409%20H%2041.493543%20V%2039.948209%20l%2073.354737%2C-0.005%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23000000%3Bstroke-width%3A5.30424%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Amiter%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22M%2060.768038%2C91.352898%20H%20118.0696%22%20id%3D%22path4635%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23000000%3Bstroke-width%3A5.30424%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Amiter%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22M%2061.351895%2C113.09545%20H%20118.65346%22%20id%3D%22path4635-6%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23000000%3Bstroke-width%3A5.30424%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Amiter%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22M%2060.599782%2C134.15462%20H%20117.90134%22%20id%3D%22path4635-9%22%2F%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22g7223-0%22%20style%3D%22opacity%3A1%3Bstroke%3A%23ffffff%22%20transform%3D%22matrix(1.6009321%2C0%2C0%2C1.6009321%2C-39.960567%2C-15.478026)%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22g7072-4%22%20transform%3D%22matrix(0.39164163%2C0%2C0%2C0.39164163%2C101.22551%2C-8.9826794)%22%20style%3D%22stroke%3A%23ffffff%22%3E%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23ffffff%3Bstroke-width%3A26.4583%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Around%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22M%20-130.19258%2C189.10654%20V%2032.002645%22%20id%3D%22path6711-7%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23ffffff%3Bstroke-width%3A26.4583%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Around%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22M%20-208.74454%2C110.5546%20H%20-51.640634%22%20id%3D%22path6711-9-8%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22g7223%22%20transform%3D%22matrix(1.1716949%2C0%2C0%2C1.1716949%2C-16.33991%2C0.79419857)%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22g7072%22%20transform%3D%22matrix(0.39164163%2C0%2C0%2C0.39164163%2C101.22551%2C-8.9826794)%22%3E%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23008000%3Bstroke-width%3A26.4583%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Around%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22M%20-130.19258%2C189.10654%20V%2032.002645%22%20id%3D%22path6711%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3Anone%3Bstroke%3A%23008000%3Bstroke-width%3A26.4583%3Bstroke-linecap%3Around%3Bstroke-linejoin%3Around%3Bstroke-miterlimit%3A4%3Bstroke-dasharray%3Anone%3Bstroke-opacity%3A1%22%20d%3D%22M%20-208.74454%2C110.5546%20H%20-51.640634%22%20id%3D%22path6711-9%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: 25% 50%;
  background-size: 10%;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem 3.0rem 1rem 5.0rem;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.pdf_btn:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.drop_area {
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px dashed #2c97de;
}

.drop_area--drag {
  border: 3px solid #2c97de;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.icon--drag {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 10em;
  / / position: relative;
  padding: 5.2%;
  animation: pulsate_icon 2.4s linear infinite alternate;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon--drop {
  display: none;
}

.or_span {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.pdf_btn--drag,
.or_span--drag,
.pdf_btn_container--drag {
  display: none;
}

.drop_info {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  / / font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  / / padding: 5 %;
}

.drop_info--drag {
  display: none;
}

.pdf_btn_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.pdf_btn_container--drag {
  display: none;
}

.drop-area--over {}

.loading {
  display: none;
}

.loading--drop {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 10em;
  padding: 5.2%;
  color: #cccccc;
  animation: rotate 2.4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pulsate_icon {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  12.5% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form name="pdf_form" action="upload_pic" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="drop_area">
        <span class="loading"><i class="fas fa-yin-yang"></i></span>
        <span class="icon"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></span>
        <div class="pdf_btn_container">
          <input type="file" name="certificate" id="certificate" accept=".pdf" style="display:none">
          <label class="pdf_btn" for="certificate">CHOOSE FILE</label>
        </div>
        <span class="or_span">OR</span>
        <span class="drop_info"><p>Drop your  <b>Certificate</b>  here</p></span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'js/script_cert.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: In your snippet there is no `form` variable and `$form` is a jQuery object, so cannot be used in the FormData constructor. Use `new FormData($form[0])` or `new FormData($form.get(0))`, both achieve the same thing, it's just a case of which syntax you prefer. Also `file` is not defined, but I assume this is just an issue with copying the code from your actual development environment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It returns empty application/octet-stream

Comment: @booyaakaashaa returned from where?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am processing the files in my python script using flask.

Comment: In which case either the HTML form is not correctly structured so that the file isn't being sent in the request (this can be checked by looking at the request payload size in the network tab of browser devtools), or the python code has an issue in it where you attempt to retrieve the request data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated the code.

Comment: `ajaxData = new FormData($(form)[0]);` is not correct. It should be `ajaxData = new FormData($form[0]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234154/discussion-between-booyaakaashaa-and-rory-mccrossan).